# pretty url using htaccess rewriterule casuing "internal server error"

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

My .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ photo.php?id=$1

RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/$ photo.php?id=$1
```

My goal is to convert the url `mysite.com/photo.php?id=31` to `mysite.com/31`. But when i visit `mysite.com/31`, all i get is:

> Internal Server Error
>
> The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was
>   unable to complete your request.
>
> Please contact the server administrator, admin@localhost and inform
>   them of the time the error occurred, and anything you might have done
>   that may have caused the error.
>
> More information about this error may be available in the server error
>   log.

Im running it on a wamp server.

Edit:

My current url looks like this: `http://localhost:8080/img/photo.php?id=1`. Do i need to add the `/img`-part to htaccess?

Comment: Where is this htaccess file, in your document root or inside the `/img/` directory? Do you have other rules elsewhere?

Comment: @JonLin its in the /img/ folder. And no other rules elsewhere

Comment: So you have this htaccess file in you `/img/` directory but you want rewrites to happen in your document root (e.g. `mysite.com/31`)?

Comment: @JonLin The root in this case would be /img/. The url is a bit missleading

Comment: Or is it that you actually want to rewrite URL's like: `mysite.com/img/31`?

Comment: Your `/` maps to your document root, `/31` will never go into the `/img` directory since it's off of the root, `/`.

Comment: @JonLin Ok, so how would i adjust the rewriterule?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to be able to access images via the URL `http://mysite.com/31`, note, there is no `/img/` directory in the URL, you need to put your rewrite rules in an htaccess file in your document root. The directory that the `img` directory is in. Since I'm also going to assume you've got other stuff on your site besides images, you're going to want to check that you are rewriting requests that aren't for images, and you can do that by checking against `%{REQUEST_FILENAME}` and the `!-f` and `!-d` flags.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/?$ /img/photo.php?id=$1 [L]
```

Also, since your existing rules are just fine if you are trying to access your images via URLs like: `http://mysite.com/img/31`, there is something else that is causing your 500 server error. **Please make sure that the rewrite module is loaded**. In WAMP, right click on the WAMP icon and go to **apache**, then **apache module** and make sure **rewrite module** is checked.

Comment: Thank you! It was turned off in wamp. The problem im facing is that right now my project is hosted in a sub directory in my wamp folder. But when i move it to my real host, i wont have the /img/ as base. But i guess i have to adjust the rules when i move the site.

Comment: @Johan You won't need to adjust your base when you move the site, just remove the `/img` from the rule's target above (which is essentially what you had originally).

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>    
    Options +FollowSymLinks    
    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_\-]+)$ photo.php?id=$1    
</IfModule>
```

Comment: the `-` doesn't need to be escaped if it's at the end or not between character spans.